# Android : Facebook share link with content

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to share a link with content in Android. I want this in Android Eclipse.

I tried in Android Studio, it was working perfectly.

> compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentTitle("How to share content")
        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.numetriclabz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/114.png"))
        .setContentDescription("simple LinkedIn integration")
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-linkedin-integration-login-tutorial/"))
        .build();
    shareDialog.show(linkContent);  // Show facebook ShareDialog
}
```

This code is working perfectly in Android Studio.

When I try this in eclipse it is not working. I add the library for FacebookSDK library , but the "ShareLinkContent" is not importing in Eclipse.

Comment: from where u download FacebookSDK library
and is it same version??

Comment: facebook SDK 4.6.0 is now not available in "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads" @Vishal Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohk got your issue

if you wanna .jar file for non compile library for eclipse you can use

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads

you can use 
https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-android-sdk-4.10.1.zip
or above version for eclipse

Comment: its having aar file. But how to add aar file into eclipse @Vishal Patel

Comment: i think some plugins available for it